# Android- how to communicate between a Service and Command Line

Tags: java, android, service

i want to make an android app running in background that receives a string from my bash script
the app uses the string to show a toast with a text
but i dont know how to send the string to the app and neither how to recive the string
help please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Intent` via `am` and send them to your service. This would look like:

```
adb shell am startservice -a com.yourpackage.action.name.SHOW_TOAST -e text "i did it"
```

And your service might look like:

```
....

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text: " + intent.getStringExtra("text"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
....
```

And add next entry to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <service  android:name="com.yourpackage.SomeService">
     <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.yourpackage.action.name.SHOW_TOAST" />
     </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

Comment: The class should be called SHOW_TOAST or what?

Comment: Nope, this is the name of Intent action. I've update the answer.

Comment: I've tested it before answering. So if something is not working for you then let me know.

Comment: but now iwant to know how to stop the service

Comment: You should read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html. It's a good description how services work.